# Transform DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am struggling with the following issue.

My DF is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    ['7890-1', '12345N', 'John', 'Intermediate'],
    ['7890-4', '30909N', 'Greg', 'Intermediate'], 
    ['3300-1', '88117N', 'Mark', 'Advanced'],
    ['2502-2', '90288N', 'Olivia', 'Elementary'],
    ['7890-2', '22345N', 'Joe', 'Intermediate'],
    ['7890-3', '72245N', 'Ana', 'Elementary']
],
columns=['Id', 'Code', 'Person', 'Level'])
print(df)
```

I would like to get such a result:

|  | Id | Code 1 | Person 1 | Level 1 | Code 2 | Person 2 | Level 2 | Code 3 | Person 3 | Level 3 | Code 4 | Person 4 | Level 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | 7890 | 12345N | John | Intermediate | 22345N | Joe | Intermediate | 72245N | Ana | Elementary | 30909N | Greg | Intermediate |
| **1** | 3300 | 88117N | Mark | Advanced | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| **2** | 2502 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 90288N | Olivia | Elementary | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the same approach as @Andrej Kesely but then sort by index after unstacking and `map` over the column names with `' '.join`.

```py
df[["Id", "No"]] = df["Id"].str.split("-", expand=True)
df_wide = df.set_index(["Id", "No"]).unstack(level=1).sort_index(axis=1,level=1)
df_wide.columns = df_wide.columns.map(' '.join)
```

Output

```
      Code 1       Level 1 Person 1  Code 2       Level 2 Person 2  Code 3  \
Id                                                                           
2502     NaN           NaN      NaN  90288N    Elementary   Olivia     NaN   
3300  88117N      Advanced     Mark     NaN           NaN      NaN     NaN   
7890  12345N  Intermediate     John  22345N  Intermediate      Joe  72245N   

         Level 3 Person 3  Code 4       Level 4 Person 4  
Id                                                        
2502         NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN  
3300         NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN  
7890  Elementary      Ana  30909N  Intermediate     Greg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df[["Id", "Id2"]] = df["Id"].str.split("-", expand=True)
x = df.set_index(["Id", "Id2"]).unstack(level=1)
x.columns = [f"{a} {b}" for a, b in x.columns]
print(
    x[sorted(x.columns, key=lambda k: int(k.split()[-1]))]
    .reset_index()
    .to_markdown()
)
```

Prints:

|  | Id | Code 1 | Person 1 | Level 1 | Code 2 | Person 2 | Level 2 | Code 3 | Person 3 | Level 3 | Code 4 | Person 4 | Level 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2502 | nan | nan | nan | 90288N | Olivia | Elementary | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 3300 | 88117N | Mark | Advanced | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 7890 | 12345N | John | Intermediate | 22345N | Joe | Intermediate | 72245N | Ana | Elementary | 30909N | Greg | Intermediate |